# JPA 2.1 ElementCollection or OneToMany for String

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity

Do anyone know how to create a `Set` of `String` type using JPA 2.1 in entity? I would like it to work as a directory, so no duplicated values could be present (like an enumeration).

I've tried:

```
 @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetClass = String.class)
  @CollectionTable(
      name = "transactions_labels",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"),
      foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "transaction_id"),
      uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "label", name = "unique_label")
  )
  @Column(name = "label")
  public Set<String> labels;
```

Unfortunately this creates duplicates in `transactions_labels` table with multiple entries containing same value in `transactions_labels.label`.

I would like JPA to check if the value exists before inserting new one.

Is this possible?

JPA persist:

```
TransactionEntity transactionEntity = new TransactionEntity();
entityManager.persist(transactionEntity);
[...]
transactionEntity.labels = new HashSet<>();
transactionEntity.labels.add("some_tag_1");
transactionEntity.labels.add("some_tag_2");
transactionEntity.labels.add("some_tag_3");
[...]
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

SQL generated by Hibernate(some fields where removed):

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        transactions
        ([...]) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    update
        transactions 
    set
        [...]
    where
        id=?
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        transactions_labels
        (id, label) 
    values
        (?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        transactions_labels
        (id, label) 
    values
        (?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        transactions_labels
        (id, label) 
    values
        (?, ?)
```

Comment: since a Set, in general, cannot have duplicated values, suggest that you DEBUG the SQL calls to the database, and post HOW you are creating/updating these persisted objects

Comment: Well, looks like there is one to many relation created on `labels` by `@ElementCollection` and only inserts on `transactions_labels` are being performed.

Maybe the whole approach is just wrong.